# iPad - CGAffineTransformMakeRotation - keeping rotation

Tags: ios, transform, cgaffinetransform

I have a heads up display (HUD) that I'm trying to get to properly rotate with the view. I created a function `orientationWillChange` that is supposed to rotate the view and that works fine, just requires a little more programming on the side of the view controller implementing it.

My main problem is that it rotates when it closes. It does some other transformations when it closes (shrinking/fading it so it disappears), but it seems to be rotating it back to "normal".

I don't want to rotate the view *another* 90 degrees, I just want to make sure it stays in the rotation it is at. How do I do that?

My closing function is as follows:

```
- (void)close {
    _windowIsShowing = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.125 animations:^{
        hudView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationDegrees * M_PI / 180);
        hudView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 animations:^{
            hudView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.4, 0.4);
            hudView.alpha = 0.0;
            backgroundColorView.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [hudWindow resignKeyWindow];
            [self release];
        }];
    }];
}
```

(fyi this is based on [CloudApp's HUD](https://github.com/cloudapp/ios/blob/master/Classes/Controllers/NPHUDController.m))